# Adjusting the speed of 2 different object on console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

I'm making a simple game like Google's Dinosaur Game. As you pass the obstacles, their speed increases as well as the Dino. What I wanna do is make Dino's speed constant while obstacles speed increases.

```
while (1)
{

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) < 0 || action) // checking if the user press SPACE
    {
        if (!action) button = _getch();

        if (button == VK_SPACE) // rest is making the dino move up and down.
        {
            action = 1;

            if (loop < 6)
            {
                std::queue<Position> tempQue = dinoPos;

                for (size_t i = 0; i < DINOSIZE; i++)
                {
                    setCursor(dinoPos.front().x, dinoPos.front().y); dinoPos.pop();
                    std::cout << " ";
                }

                for (size_t i = 0; i < DINOSIZE; i++)
                {
                    setCursor(tempQue.front().x, tempQue.front().y - 1);
                    tempQue.front().y -= 1;
                    dinoPos.push(tempQue.front());
                    tempQue.pop();
                    std::cout << "D";
                }
            }
            loop++;
            if (loop == 12)
            {
                loop = 0;
                action = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(speed)); // using this for speeding up the game
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `sleep_for`. It can sleep for longer and offers no timing guarantees. What you want it a fixed update game loop. You can look in popular game engines to see how it's implemented.

But it boils down to the following **pseudo-code**:

```
//mainloop
// get a number of frame based on time.
// take a number of frame higher than expected frame rate. say 10 ms.
int frame = now() / frameDuration; 

while(true)
{
    int frameNow = now() / frameDuration;
    
    while(frame != frameNow)
    {
        Update();
        frame++;
    }

    render();
}
```

With the following update function: (pseudo-code again)

```
// there, you advance you object for a fixing duration, say 10 ms.
// just use different speed for each
Update()
{
    obstacle.position += obstacleSpeed * frameDuration;
    character.position += characterSpeed * frameDuration;
}
```